# DVC imports authentication to blob storage

Tags: python, dvc

I'm using [DVC](https://dvc.org/) to track and version data that is stored locally on the file system and in Azure Blob storage.

My setup is as follows:

- `DataProject1`, it uses a local file location as a remote therefore it does not require any authentication.
- `DataProject2`, it uses Azure Blob Storage as a remote, it is using sas_token for authentication, I can push pull data to/from the remote when I'm within this project.
- `MLProject`, it uses dvc import to import data from `DataProjec1` and `DataProject2`.

When I run the import with the command against `DataProject1` everything works fine:

`dvc import -o 'data/project1' 'https://company.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/proj/_git/DataProject1' 'data/project1'` - Successful

Howevever when I run a similar command against `DataProject2` the command fails:

`dvc import -o 'data/project2' 'https://company.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/proj/_git/DataProject2' 'data/project2'` - it fails with:

> ERROR: unexpected error - Operation returned an invalid status 'This
> request is not authorized to perform this operation using this
> permission.'  ErrorCode:AuthorizationPermissionMismatch.

I would like to configure the `dvc import` so that I can set the required `sas_token` but I cannot find a way to do that.

Comment: Have you tried the documentation? https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/remote/modify#example-some-azure-authentication-methods

Comment: A normal remote in the project where I'm issuing the import did not work, but setting a `--global` remote there, as @Shcheklein suggeted, works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens since DVC is not using `MLProject`'s config when it clones and does `dvc fetch` in the `DataProject2` during the `import`. And it doesn't know where it can find the token (clearly, it's not in the Git repo, right?).

There are a few ways to specify it: [`global/system` configs](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/config#--system) and/or [environment variables](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/remote/modify#authenticate-with-environment-variables).

To implement the first option:

On a machine where you do `dvc import`, you could create a remote in the `--global`, or `--system` configs with the same name and specify the token there. Global config fields will be merged with the config in the `DataProject2` repo when DVC is pulling data to import.

```bash
dvc remote add --global <DataProject2-remote-name> azure://DataProject2/storage
dvc remote modify --global <DataProject2-remote-name> account_name <name>
dvc remote modify --global <DataProject2-remote-name> sas_token <token>
```

The second option:

```bash
export AZURE_STORAGE_SAS_TOKEN='mysecret'
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT='myaccount'
```

Please give it a try, let me know if that works or not.

Comment: Thanks @Shcheklein, I was not familiar with global/system configs and so I did not know that import was able to read those configs. Having tried that the import worked! However, one thing is not clear, even though I deleted the global settings  using `dvc config --global -u <setting-name>` (I could verify being deleted on my Mac at the path `$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/dvc/config`), when  running the dvc import again, oddly that still works. Does DVC use some credentials caching and how can I clear the cache? Thanks

Comment: Actually my earlier comment is misleading. Upon more testing, I understand that a dvc update might give the impression it has cached the credentials while it has not. This happens if the remote did not change, the `dvc update` can successfully check the `DataProject` dvc metadata as that does not require it hitting the underlying storage, and if the hash matches there is nothing else that it needs to do so it returns a "successful" message `data/prod1.dvc' didn't change, skipping`.  I wrongly interpreted that as  credentials being cached but this seems not the case.